# Django open an external link passing POST data

Tags: python, django, post

In my Django project i need to call from my function into my views.py an external page passing in POST format some data.
i do this:

in urls.py:

```
...    
url(r'^gocard/(?P<lic_num>\w+)/$', go_ccredit),
...
```

in my views.py i create the function go_ccredit:

```
def go_ccredit(request, lic_num=None, **kwargs):

    requests.post('https://www.example.com/form_test', data={'lid':lic_num,})
```

but i got an error because no HTTPResponse vas returned, and no page was open.

I need to open an external page because i need to populate some form field with my data (using POST) and some other have to be populated by user.

How can i open from my django function my external page passing data in POST ?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: first of all do req = requests.post('https://www.example.com/form_test', data={'lid':lic_num,})
and then print(req) to see what is the response from post request on  example.com/form_test

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i have to open the link passing my values

Comment: What do you meant by open the link?

Comment: redirect to the page and use my value for fill the form

Comment: Tell me If I am wrong.You want to redirect to a page so that some of the values on that page are prefilled and some are to be entered by user on the same page?and user will submit the form?

Comment: yes correct. thanka